# How do I add multiple values to a parameter of the YouTube API search.list query?

Tags: url, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube API v3. Creating a url that returns search results via search: list.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

I want to filter the results by duration. But I want both "short" and "medium" length videos. For various reasons I want to avoid doing this in two searches. Is there any way to pass two values to the videoDuration parameter in the url?

I can't seem to find any documentation that gives a clear yes or no. I've tried:

```
&videoDuration=short,medium
&videoDuration=(short,medium)
&videoDuration=short||medium
```

No avail. Does anyone know whether this is possible, and if so, how?

Many thanks!

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Comment: No, I wasn't. Seems that it is, as indicated below, impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. You have to make two requests for that. If you go to "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list" and click on "Try now!" You can see all available options in the videoDuration field. If the values are listed that way, only they are accepted, nothing else.